# ios UIView animation (onUpdate)

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

`UIView animatWithDuration` has an optional param for `completion`, but I need one for `update`

The whole idea is I need a block that runs on EVERY frame of animation. I figure I can spoof this with a `NSInterval`, but that just seems hoaky.

*Thoughts?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CADisplayLink instead. Works just like an NSTimer, but fires exactly once every frame and will be perfectly in sync with the animation.

Here's how you set one up:

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(step)];
[link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Your animation code

```
- (void)step
{
    //do something related to your animation
}
```

Then when the animation finishes

```
[self.displayLink invalidate];
self.displayLink = nil;
```

Comment: Sounds good. I didn't know I had to implement `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, but a quick google search helped out on that one.